# Separating $y$'s and $x$'s

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am doing this initial value problem where I have the equation $y' + \frac{3}{x} y=\frac{\cos(x)}{x^3} $. I know how to do these kinds of problems but I am having trouble getting the $x$ to the right side and the $y$ into the left side, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not respectful to the people who've written answers to delete your question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to treat this like a first order linear (non-separable) differential equation. Multiply both sides by $x^3$. You'll see that the left side looks like the result of a product rule expansion, giving you
$$[yx^3]’=\cos(x)$$
Then, you can integrate, to yield
$$yx^3=-\sin x + C$$
and divide by $x^3$ to get
$$y=-\frac{\sin x}{x^3} + Cx^{-3}$$

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I just multiplied both by x^3, but what does it looking like the product rule expansion tell me? I would sitll have x and y in left side

Comment: @A.B. See if you can do it now

Comment: No, I meant I did get what you have, but I don't see how I can remove the x^3?

Comment: Thank you, my last question is regarding what am I integrating in respect to. I am assuming the right side is in respect to dx, but what is left side in respect to?

Comment: @A.B. Also dx. y is a function of x, so the left side is just a function of x.

Comment: Thank you so much!